# Integrating around branch point of analytic carrier "totally" gives zero. Why?

Tags: complex-analysis

I noticed this. Consider the **Cauchy integral theorem**

$$\oint_\gamma f(z) dz = 0$$

where $\gamma$ is a closed loop encircling a point $c$. If $f$ is holomorphic on a simply connected open set containing $\gamma$ and $c$ then the above holds good true.

But now suppose we consider an analytic "multi valued relation" or *carrier* like $f(z) = z^{1/3}$ instead of a regular function. This thing is still "holomorphic" in a sense (any "sheet" on a cut plane, in particular, is holomorphic on that cut plane) *except at $z = 0$*. But if you take a Cauchy integral where $\gamma$ loops 3 times around $z = 0$, so that it goes around the 3-branched surface of the relation in a closed loop on the branched surface, you also get out $0$ from the integral! As though it were holomorphic at $0$! But it's not! Why this behavior, despite the singularity? Obviously the converse of a theorem is not always equivalent to the original theorem, but why in particular does this multi-valued relation "mimick" a holomorphic function at a point where it's clearly not holomorphic?

FWIW, here's the proof. Let the curve be parameterized by $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$ which loops 3 times so $t \in [0, 6\pi]$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\oint_\gamma z^{1/3} dz &= \int_{0}^{6\pi} f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{6\pi} (e^{it})^{1/3} ie^{it} dt\\
&= \int_{0}^{6\pi} e^{\frac{1}{3} it} ie^{it} dt\\
&= i \int_{0}^{6\pi} e^{\frac{4}{3} it} dt\\
&= i \left[-\frac{3}{4} i e^{\frac{4}{3} it}\right]_{0}^{6\pi} \\
&= i \left[-\frac{3}{4} i \left(e^{\frac{4}{3} 6\pi i} - 1\right)\right] \\
&= i \left[-\frac{3}{4} i (e^{8 \pi i} - 1)\right] \\
&= i \left[-\frac{3}{4} i (1 - 1)\right] \\
&= 0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: What is the integral of $1/z^2$ along a circle around the origin?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez 0?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez So it's just sheer coincidence? Is there an example of a MVR with a similar branch point (algebraic, approaches a limiting value) with a nonzero "residue" there?

Comment: Well, your function is holomorphic on its Riemann surface, and your integral is the internal along a closed simple curve around a point in that surface, so its value is zero. But as you say that the integral along a closed curve is zero does not tell you anything.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'd say we are using that $f(z) = z^{1/3}$ has a primitive on its Riemann surface $S$, this way we obtain that $\int_\gamma z^{1/3}dz = 0$ whenever $\gamma$ is a closed curve on $S$, ie whenever $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z}$ is divisible by $3$. And $\log z$ also has a primitive on its Riemann surface, but on thatone there is no closed curve around $0$.

Comment: @mike4ty4 See [the representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface#Examples) of the Riemann surface for $z^{1/2}, z^{1/3}$ and $\log z$. Can you see what are the closed contours on those ?